# Understanding word2vec vectors representation

Tags: nlp, word2vec, gensim

I'm trying to obtain the `word2vec` representation of few words using `gensim`.

At present, this is the model that I have:

```
model = Word2Vec(desc, size=1, seed=7, window=1, iter=1000)
```

And the current output is

```
Ansible automate 0.37919244170188904
Docker container -0.05218552052974701
Ansible automation 0.39010459184646606
Automate Ansible 0.1009570062160492
Contain Docker 0.41532352566719055
Dock contain -0.38013115525245667
Dock container -0.17561538517475128
```

I'm wondering why `Contain Docker` is closer to `Ansible automate` and `Ansible automation` than it is from the other terms which contain the word `Docker`, `Container` etc.

How can I train the word2vec model to get this sorted out?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, consider this: Word2Vec generates this representation by looking at the context (neighboring words, here with a window of 1) of each word or n-gram (e.g. pair of words such as Contain Docker).

Your are using a **uni-dimensional representation** of those pairs of words. Even in a particular training text such as yours which seems to be revolving around a unique subject (i.e. docker), a unique value as representation means a unique dimension in the "semantic space". This yields really **poor representation power**, and Word2Vec models are usually trained with more than 300 hundreds dimension to fully capture the semantic of words. And usually, more is better (but not always).

I hence suggest that you increase the size of your vectors (try different values, such as 100 and 200).

To see if the new representation makes sense, I suggest to use Multidimensional Scaling, which enables to project N-dimensional data on a plan. See for instance the answers to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/63589/228696)

---

**What if you still want to use a uni-dimensional encoding ?**

For a training text about emotions, it could mean a positive vs. negative dimension (example representations: happy = 0.85, sad = -0.94). In your case, I have no idea and suggest to plot a selection of words along this axis, to see if there are any obvious pattern for having high value or low value.